# Python Scripts for mac, how to run a program and get value back

Tags: python

I am trying to build a script in python to mac OS, I need the script to run two other scripts; the only thing my scripts does is run a website, and return value 1 or 0.

I just need to get the values, in windows i am getting then from CMD with "Exit value".

But i am new to mac, and in my job i need do it i mac.

After i get those values, i need to write a file that says 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess
r = subprocess.call(['script', 'argument1', ...])
```

Now `r` is the return value from your script. To write that to a file (I assume you want it as text):

```
open('statusfile.txt', 'w').write('%d\n' % r)
```

Comment: When i call the process, its always says to me the file is not exit's, even in windows.